# EF Code First Migrations causing CA1701 and CA1703

Tags: entity-framework-5, code-analysis, resx, entity-framework-migrations

Upon enabling migrations for my code-first EF 5 context I started to receive a TON of CA1701 and CA1703 code analysis violations due to the migration history string being added to the project's resx file.

I do not care to disable CA1701 and CA1703 and also do not want to suppress 100ish messages for each individual migration that's going to be added.  Is there a way to mark a resx's xml file or individual resx entry as // <auto-generated /> so this stops happening?  If I have to disable the two rules, then so be it just hoping that's not the only sane answer!

TIA
Jason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just noticed this today, myself. You can suppress the CA1701 and CA1703 warnings at the resource level with the following in either your AssemblyInfo.cs or a GlobalSuppressions.cs file:

```
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming",
    "CA1701:ResourceStringCompoundWordsShouldBeCasedCorrectly",
    Justification = "The auto-genererated code from code first migrations trigger this warning.",
    Scope = "resource", Target = "Full.Namespace.To.Your.Migrations.NameOfYourMigration.resources")]
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming",
    "CA1703:ResourceStringsShouldBeSpelledCorrectly",
    Justification = "The auto-genererated code from code first migrations trigger this warning.",
    Scope = "resource", Target = "Full.Namespace.To.Your.Migrations.NameOfYourMigration.resources")]
```

You'll need to do this for each of your migrations, but it's much better than suppressing each warning individually.

Comment: Great answer... Easiest way to get this working is
- Suppress one of the existing warnings into the globalsuppressions file via Code Analysis window.
- Copy the code block from the answer into the globalsuppressions file
- Replace the target attribute's value from the suppressed message to the target attribute for the above code block.

Answer (score 7):

I personally got fed up with manually keeping my suppressions up to date (after 2 hours), so I wrote the following T4 template:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

<#
    var @namespace = CallContext.LogicalGetData("NamespaceHint");
    var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);

    const int timestampLength = 15;
    var timestampWildcards = new string('?', timestampLength);
    var paths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, timestampWildcards + "_*.cs");

    const int timestampUnderscoreLength = timestampLength + 1;

    var classNames = from path in paths
                     let fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)
                     where !fileName.EndsWith(".designer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                     where fileName.Length> timestampUnderscoreLength 
                     select fileName.Substring(timestampUnderscoreLength);

    foreach(var className in classNames)
    {
        var fullClassName = @namespace + "." + className;
#>
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1701:ResourceStringCompoundWordsShouldBeCasedCorrectly", Scope = "resource", Target = "<#=fullClassName#>.resources")]
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1703:ResourceStringsShouldBeSpelledCorrectly", Scope = "resource", Target = "<#=fullClassName#>.resources")]
<#
    }
#>
```

Create a T4 template with this content in the same folder as the migrations, the generated code will automatically contain suppressions for the resources, e.g.

```
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1701:ResourceStringCompoundWordsShouldBeCasedCorrectly", Scope = "resource", Target = "LzSoftware.Collectables.Domain.EntityFramework.Migrations.InitialCreation.resources")]
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1703:ResourceStringsShouldBeSpelledCorrectly", Scope = "resource", Target = "LzSoftware.Collectables.Domain.EntityFramework.Migrations.InitialCreation.resources")]
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1701:ResourceStringCompoundWordsShouldBeCasedCorrectly", Scope = "resource", Target = "LzSoftware.Collectables.Domain.EntityFramework.Migrations.RemovedAdministratorRoleFromSettings.resources")]
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1703:ResourceStringsShouldBeSpelledCorrectly", Scope = "resource", Target = "LzSoftware.Collectables.Domain.EntityFramework.Migrations.RemovedAdministratorRoleFromSettings.resources")]
```

Comment: If you move the migrations Configuration.cs file, Code Analysis will issue the rule violations based on the location of that file, not where the actual migrations (and T4 template) are located.  To fix that, I had to hardcode the namespace variable with the  namespace for my moved (and renamed) Configuration.cs file.  Just an FYI for anyone in a similar circumstance.

Thanks a bunch for authoring this, should really be marked as the answer.